# Tapping on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationcontroller

I want a button tap effect for a UIBarButtonItem. My navigation bar has black tint color:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

So when I tap on any UIBarButtonItem on it, I do not get a button tapping effect. If I change the tint color to some other color like gray, it works. But I want only the black color there in the tint.

When you tap on a button, it color fades and you feel the tapping effect. That is because of touchUpInside action associated with UIButton class but nothing such event is there with UIBarButtonItem. I can get that effect with UIBarButtonItem if I set the Tint color of Navigaiton bar to other than black or dark gray.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this done by setting the nav bae style:

```
myController.navigationBarStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always set your UIBarButtonItem custom view to a UIButton, then youll have whatever effect from UIButton that you like...